# Galeria de imagenes con gestor

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Buenas! alguien me puede orientar o pasar un tutorial donde me den una idea de qué método utilizar si quiero crear una galería de imágenes que se pueden: agregar nueva imagen, eliminar imagen, modificar.
Esto lo quiero agregar a mi sitio web y modificar todo desde la web, no desde el código fuente.

Comment: Te sugiero que visites [help/dont-ask], para ver como realizar la pregunta y que no te la cierren

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te sea de utilidad
[DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)  Es una librería drag and drop que permite eliminar, modificar y agregar, encontraras muchos tutoriales en la web
Saludos